# Canvas-lms update rails 2.3.5 to 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, rails-3-upgrade

I am going to work on the open source Canvas-lms. Its using rails 2.3.5 but i am familar with rails 3.2.12.

1. How to upgrade rails 2.3.5 to rails 3.2.12.
2. What are the challenges.
3. What is the best way to do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Include this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
```

Then run the command

```
bundle update rails
```

I think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Just upgrading the rails version doesn't change the api working of Rails. We have to lots of manual work to make this upgrade successful.

Comment: Canvas is a massive codebase, with an upgrade effort already underway. You'll need to communicate with the developers to find out if/when Rails 3 compatability is ready.